# Display multiple frames from a DCM image using python pydicom

Tags: python, pydicom

I am trying to read and display a dicom image. The image has 49 frames. The PixelData has 24887296 elements in the array. Since the pixel_array cannot be used directly, please guide me on how to display the multiple frames from .dcm image? The input image is bscan image.

**Below is Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pydicom

dataset = pydicom.dcmread('bscan.dcm')
frame_generator = pydicom.encaps.generate_pixel_data_frame(dataset.PixelData)

if 'PixelData' in dataset:
    rows = int(dataset.Rows)
    cols = int(dataset.Columns)
    print("Image size.......: {rows:d} x {cols:d}, {size:d} bytes".format(
        rows=rows, cols=cols, size=len(dataset.PixelData)))
    if 'PixelSpacing' in dataset:
        print("Pixel spacing....:", dataset.PixelSpacing)

plt.imshow(dataset.pixel_array)
plt.show()
```

**Output**

```
Image size.......: 496 x 512, 24887296 bytes
Pixel spacing....: [0.011606, 0.003872]
Slice location...: (missing)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-bef78c9b38bf> in <module>()
     10 print("Slice location...:", dataset.get('SliceLocation', "(missing)"))
     11 
---> 12 plt.imshow(dataset.pixel_array)
     13 plt.show()

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pydicom/pixel_data_handlers/numpy_handler.py in get_pixeldata(ds, read_only)
    274         raise AttributeError(
    275             "Unable to convert the pixel data as the following required "
--> 276             "elements are missing from the dataset: " + ", ".join(missing)
    277         )
    278 

AttributeError: Unable to convert the pixel data as the following required elements are missing from the dataset: SamplesPerPixel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception message says, your image is missing a mandatory DICOM tag.
A possibility to patch this concrete image would be to set it manually:

```
dataset = pydicom.dcmread('bscan.dcm')
if 'SamplesPerPixel' not in dataset:
    dataset.SamplesPerPixel = 1  # or whatever the correct value should be, depending on the data
```

Provided that the other tags are correctly set, you could calculate it:

```
dataset.SamplesPerPixel = len(dataset.PixelData) / (dataset.get('NumberOfFrames', 1) * dataset.Rows * dataset.Columns * dataset.BitsAllocated / 8)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. As you said, I had to set dataset.SamplesPerPixel to 1.